# How do i create a Random Number Generator Function for haskell tetris game

Tags: haskell, tetris

my question is very straight forward, i want to have a function in my haskell code that works as following: i invoke it and it returns me a random Integer. I use it to generate my tetrominoes based on the generated numbers, any ideas?

EDIT, here's how my code that doenst works, looks right now
the codes would be something like:

Point is a data struc that i've made by myself, it doesnt really matters.
The problem with using unsafePerform is that it repeats the same number everytime

```
getRandomInt :: Int
getRandomInt = unsafePerformIO (getStdRandom (randomR (1, 7)))

getRandomTetromino :: [Point]
getRandomTetromino = getRT getRandomInt

getRT :: Int -> [Point]
getRT c
    | c == 1 = [ Point 5 1 "T", Point 5 0 "T", Point 6 1 "T", Point 4 1 "T"]
    | c == 2 = [ Point 5 1 "Z", Point 5 0 "Z", Point 4 1 "Z", Point 4 2 "Z"]
    | c == 3 = [ Point 5 1 "I", Point 5 0 "I", Point 5 2 "I", Point 5 3 "I"]
    | c == 4 = [ Point 5 1 "L", Point 6 1 "L", Point 4 1 "L", Point 6 0 "L"]
    | c == 5 = [ Point 5 1 "J", Point 5 0 "J", Point 6 0 "J", Point 5 2 "J"]
    | c == 6 = [ Point 5 1 "S", Point 5 0 "S", Point 6 0 "S", Point 4 1 "S"]
    | c == 7 = [ Point 5 0 "O", Point 6 0 "O", Point 6 1 "O", Point 5 1 "O"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using this :

```
import System.Random
import Control.Monad (replicateM)

main = replicateM 10 (randomIO :: IO Int) >>= print
```

Comment: are there any ways of storing those integers in a variable?

Comment: DO not use comments to ask a question. Please make another question.